# Aiogram | Отображение команды в чате при нажатии на инлайн кнопку

Tags: python, aiogram

Всем привет, увидел одну интересную механику в одном боте:

[image: Механика]

При нажатии на кнопку "Найти", команда @BetBoom_online_bot m= вписывается сама в окно ввода пользователя.

Изыскал всю библиотеку в надежде найти это, но увы, пришлось писать сюда(